# Save livestream to disk with VLC Web Plugin

Tags: video-streaming, vlc

Using VLC player, a UDP multicast can be saved to a local file:

```
vlc -vvv udp://@239.100.0.37:1234 --sout=file/ps:c:\go.mpg
```

**Now, is it possible to save the same stream with the VLC Web Plugin?**

I've tried various variants, but to no success. Also, I've found no documentation for options available in the VLC Web Plugin. The only thing I found is [this](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=60983&p=149247) post from 2008 when someone seemingly managed to get this done with a webcam. Maybe saving to local disk from Web Plugin has been restricted for security reasons in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VLC Web plugin does not have any sout capabilities for security reasons just like you guessed. If it had, it would be possible for any website to overwrite all contents or items in the user context, which would be a major security risk.